# On redirecting to a View, slide it to the specific part of the page using #id - Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, http-redirect

I have a route which redirects to a controller which tells view to show. But how can I go to a particular part of the page. Let me Explain:

I am using fullpage.js library to create a page breakpoints. 
for example: `/home#firstPage` , `/home#secondPage` and so on. When I am redirected to /home I would like to go to a particular section of the page. All I need is a way to enter #3rdPage in url.

**Where and How do I put this to see it action?**

## my Routes

```
Route::get('/home_done', ['as' => 'home_done','uses' => 'HomeController@home']);
```

## my Controller

```
public function home()
{
    return view('home_done');
}
```

I would like to do something like:

```
    return view('home_done#3rdPage');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should setup a new function and route to redirect the users to correct page after executing your logic:

```
public function home()
{
    return view('home_done');
}

public function step_3()
{
    // do something and redirect
    return redirect('home_done#3rdPage');
}
```

Using `view` don't work since you are loading a file, not the page.

Comment: It does not work :/ . the browser keeps on loading finally the url is set but page fails to load. this is the code I used : Route::get('/home_done', function () 
{
    return redirect('home_done#3rdPage');
});

Comment: This is creating a redirect look. You should use redirect elsewhere. Keep the `home()` as it is.

Comment: Niraj Shah can you show full code. by what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You need change your behavior in JS, when a user comes to your page without a `#` consider it equal of `#firstpage`.

and in your html manage all over pages by properly generate urls with `#what_you_need`.

in your blade example:

```
<a href="<?php echo route("home_done") . "#firstpage"; ?>">firstpage</a> 
//OR 
<a href="<?php echo route("home_done") ?>">firstpage</a> //because this is the same for your JS
<a href="<?php echo route("home_done") . "#secondpage"; ?>">secondpage</a>
```

or blade syntax

```
<a href="{{ route("home_done") . "#firstpage"; }}">firstpage</a> 
//OR 
<a href="{{ route("home_done") }}">firstpage</a> //because this is the same for your JS
<a href="{{ route("home_done") . "#secondpage"; }}">secondpage</a>
```

Comment: this is a way to set links to slide over the content but I need a way to go to a particular part of the page as it loads.